# access node title in field.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I would like to access the title of the node a field belongs to in a `field.tpl.php` file. My goal is to transform the field into a `mailto` link that would use the node title as the subject field.
Is it possible to access that information at this point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the node values from: `$element['#object']`: The entity to which the field is attached.

So in this case if the field is a node field the $element['#object'] is the node object.

```
print $element['#object']->title;
```

Documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7

Comment: Thanks! I just found it meandring around the aptana debugger and the docs. That's just what I was looking for!